# Connected to the wireless but no internet access

Tags: networking, wireless, intel-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit

On Thursday the 16th March 2017 Ubuntu software up-grader proposed to me a "Partial upgrade"

I pressed OK and it executed this partial upgrade

After the upgrade I had no Ethernet connection

After a lot of research I found that it could be driver conflicts so I downloaded my Ethernet drivers again

That solved the issue, but I then discovered I had no wireless access and connection

I was sure it was something related to the drivers and I did some research I found it could be something related to compact

So I downloaded compact and compiled and installed it

Now I see the wireless card and I can connect to wireless, but I have no Internet connection.

I did a lot of research and I downloaded my wireless card drivers again.

Note that I'm using my Android phone for tethering as wifi spot (as I did in the past and with no problems).

I can ping 8.8.8.8 but I can't surf the net

More exactly this is my `ping 8.8.8.8` result:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=40 time=69.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=40 time=66.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=40 time=72.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=40 time=69.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=40 time=67.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=40 time=67.6 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 66.755/68.888/72.227/1.776 ms
```

`mtr 8.8.8.8` output
[image: mtr 8.8.8.8 output]

`ifconfig` output

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8c:73:6e:bb:e5:2d  
          inet addr:192.168.11.114  Bcast:192.168.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8e73:6eff:febb:e52d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:72202 errors:0 dropped:5 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40210 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27221264 (27.2 MB)  TX bytes:5133806 (5.1 MB)
          Interrupt:26 Base address:0x6000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4541 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4541 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:581657 (581.6 KB)  TX bytes:581657 (581.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:f8:ae:d3:a5:09  
          inet addr:192.168.43.107  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fef8:aeff:fed3:a509/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3706 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:342087 (342.0 KB)  TX bytes:661461 (661.4 KB)
```

`lshw -class` network output:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 73
       serial: fc:f8:ae:d3:a5:09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-67-generic firmware=17.352738.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:28 memory:f0600000-f0601fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 8c:73:6e:bb:e5:2d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.044.02-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.11.114 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0500000-f0500fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
```

1. How I can "delete" the partial upgrade done on Thursday. I'm scared that this partial upgrade will cause other problems I haven't recognized yet.
2. How I can solve all my connection issues?

**UPDATE**

Effectively it seems something related to the proxy

```
env | grep -i proxy

http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.eng.it:3128/
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1
https_proxy=https://username:password@proxy.eng.it:3128/

$ curl www.google.com
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: proxy.eng.it
```

But I unselected the proxy as showed in this image
[image: Proxy unselection]

And this issue never happened before

I'll try to investigate

**UPDATE 2**

In the following image there are the results of `traceroute` and `dig` commands

[image: Traceroute and dig results]

**UPDATE 3**

In the following image you can see the result of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `ps aux | grep -i dns`

[image: Cat resolv.conf and ps results]

Comment: As you wrote in the question, you are connected to the internet. `ping` works perfectly. can you please provide example for problems you are facing (can't surf the net)?

Comment: Can you please check if you are using any `proxy` which cause the surfing problem? please issue `env | grep -i proxy` and add it to your question

Comment: I simply tried to connect to google (www.google.it) and no success.... I tried several other sites but I was not able in connection

Comment: what is the result of `curl www.google.com` ?

Comment: Your nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` is 192.168.10.1. Your ethernet is connected at 192.168.11.114. At the same time, your wireless is connected at 192.168.43.107. Where did all these numbers come from? They are all in different subnets (x.10, x.11 and x.43) and probably wrong. Please explain.

Comment: @chili555 this is the point: I don't know the reason of all these numbers; I never touched the resolv.conf and before the "partial upgrade" I never had these issues

Answer (score 3):

We have no idea where the extra subnet numbers come from. Let's try to restore all settings to default. First:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Make sure that these lines read as I've indicated:

```
dns=dnsmasq

managed=false
```

If either are not as I state, change them. All the remainder of the file should remain untouched. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Also do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

Restore the file to read:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Next, click the Network Manager icon and select 'Edit Connections.' Select your ethernet connection and go to IPv4 settings. Set the Method to Automatic (DHCP). If there are any present, remove any other entries such as DNS nameservers.

Do the same process with wireless. Save and close the edit window. Here is an example of the correct configuration:

[image]

You do not want both ethernet and wireless connected at the same time. Detach the ethernet cable and reboot. Do you connect? Can you reach the internet?

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Done what yuo suggested but no internet access; i can ping 8.8.8.8 but result of `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` is `ping: unknown host www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: What does this tell us? `traceroute www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: Also: `dig www.ubuntu.com` Please paste the results here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: please see my UPDATE 2 edit; I added a screenshot of the requested commands....

Comment: And this is the paste link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24220352/

Comment: May we see a paste of: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and also: `ps aux | grep -i dns` We wonder if *dnsmasq* is running.

Comment: Please see my UPDATE 3; there you can see a screenshot of suggested  commands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55768/discussion-between-chili555-and-angelo-immediata).

Comment: May we continue tomorrow? I had a private problem and I left office

Comment: Sure, give me a time in UTC that you'd like to chat, please.

Comment: Sorry I was busy.... well I'm in Italy so what about  4pm UTC? It should be 5pm here in italy (CET)

Comment: I will only have about 30 minutes then. I will meet you in chat. After that time, I will again be available at about 7:00 pm UTC (1900).

Comment: Ok otherwise we can meet around 3pm UTC if you prefer

Comment: I'll meet you in chat at 3:00 pm UTC!

Comment: hi i had no news.... can we schedule a new chat? just to be sure... since i never used chat here... how does it work?

Comment: Just click here and I will be there at the time you tell me you are available: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55768/discussion-between-chili555-and-angelo-immediata

Comment: sorry yesterday i had some issues. If for you it's ok i'll contact to you today... thank you

Comment: Hi sorry I have been really busy I noticed that by connecting in wi fi I can't surf the net by browser but skype is working

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, you seems to have a problem with a proxy which disturb your surfing.

Surfing the web without this problematic proxy can be done using:

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Comment: I did what you suggested... it didn't work.  `curl www.google.com` result is: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com`

Comment: what is the result of `curl 172.217.22.14` (using one of google ips)?

Comment: what is the result of `cat /etc/resolv.conf ` ?

Comment: `curl 172.217.22.14`  result is `<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"><TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>301 Moved</H1>The document has moved<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.</BODY></HTML>` `cat /etc/resolv.conf` result is `nameserver 192.168.10.1
nameserver 161.27.15.15 `

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after installing KDE NEON i had the same issue.
Resolved following the instructions on this post [Connected to Wifi but no internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790745/connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet) and chili55 instructions on resolv.conf file.
My resolv.conf has this values (default ones on live usb):
nameserver 127.0.0.53
In my OS the resolv.conf file is located in /run/NetworkManager/ with a symlink in /etc/
I had to undo the firts part of the instructions about NetworkManager.conf, because that left the machine without wifi.
I hope this comment help other users.
Thank God for this great community.