# Wireless connection works, but there's no internet access

Tags: networking, wireless

When a try to use my home wireless network, the computer connects with no problem but it can't get access to any site.

As I said, this is not a duplicate, because I've tried the solutions of similar questions.
[image: screenshot of Firefox error message]

I've tried to set to *Ignore* the IPv6 configuration
[image: screenshot of IPv6 setting]

But it doesn't work.
This is the output of `ifconfig`

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 3c:97:0e:55:48:39  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 32859  bytes 29541588 (29.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 31370  bytes 4120284 (4.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 19  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5981  bytes 446268 (446.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5981  bytes 446268 (446.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0b1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fd2a:adf5:5a82:1:4d6f:ce42:9445:43b6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::1f34:3cfb:de22:dfd0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd2a:adf5:5a82:1:de18:9351:9296:6c38  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 68:94:23:77:56:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9571  bytes 1125379 (1.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1408  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2756  bytes 423113 (423.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And this is the output of `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0b1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Movistar_15163600"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: B4:EE:B4:6A:6F:74   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:21   Missed beacon:0
```

This is the output of `route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

Comment: What IPv4 method have you set?

Comment: Do you have other devices connected to the same wireless network that have internet access? Are they using IPv4? What other solutions have you tried, exactly?

Comment: The IPv4 is in *Automatic(DHCP)* mode. I'm connected through my android device, and it works perfectly. I don't really know weather it's using IPv4.

Comment: I've tried this ones: https://askubuntu.com/questions/790745/connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1618934
https://askubuntu.com/questions/653355/wireless-connected-but-no-internet-access